# How can I make a popup window that allows the user to click a link, close the window, and open the link in the first window?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, hyperlink

This is pretty much what I want to do....

So, the user is browsing my site and they click on a "View by categories" link, this link opens a pop-up window with a series of pictures, that link to different parts of my site. When the user clicks one of those, I want to be able to close the pop-up window and open the link in the original window.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **wouldn't recommend** using pop-up for navigation because of pop-up blockers. Use some in-document solutions:

You can use Fancybox jQuery plugin for this: http://fancybox.net/

It has cool functionality to insert a bunch of HTML into its popup-style window.

After clicking a link in your fancybox window the document will reload.

**EDIT:**

```
<a id="categories-trigger" href="#categories">View by categories</a>
<div class="hidden-categories">
  <div id="categories"> 
    <!-- Your code from the link you provided. Only from inside <body> tag -->
  </div> 
</div>
```

and JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $("#categories-trigger").fancybox({ /* fancybox parameters here */ });
    });
</script>
```

You need to include jQUery and jquery.fancybox JS scripts of course.

and additional CSS code:

```
.hidden-categories #categories{
  display:none;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
#categories{
  overflow: auto;
  width: 820px;
  height: 820px;
}
```

My mistake was that fancybox content can't be hidden by default but only in a container. After these changes fancybox will work.

**EDIT 3**

Try to change JS code to this one:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#categories-trigger").fancybox({ /* fancybox parameters here */ });
});
```

The script will execute after loading images.

Comment: You do have a point with the pop-up blockers, but i'm not sure how to use that for html, http://yeahcarmelo.tumblr.com/picturecatagory, this is the page that I need to show..

Comment: Perfect, let me try this out and i'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hm... I did what you said and added everything in but it isn't working, it's just adding #categories to the url.. I used both codes you gave me and put the js code in <script> tags, and imported all the JS scripts too.

Comment: The problem lies in that you include jQuery 3 times! :). plugins should be always included After jQuery and you include jquery twice after Fancybox script.

Comment: You didn't. You have one more near bebas.js  script

Comment: Whoops, just noticed that. Ok so now I have 1 jQuery (I think)... and is this correct..?
<script type="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">
$(function(){
  $("#categories-trigger").fancybox({ 
                                'opacity'       : true,
    'overlayShow' : false,
    'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'none'

 });
});
</script>

Comment: Make sure the page is updated as well, the "Are you bored?" link should have 1 ?, not 2. Because the page doesn't always update for me.

Comment: I edited my answer again. My mistake was in a way of hiding content. `<div class="hidden-categories">` with content inside it can be anywhere.

Comment: Alright I changed everything but it's still just adding #categories to the url :/

Comment: Edited my post - add some additional CSS

Comment: Nothing changed, do I need to upload the pictures that came with fancybox somewhere? Cause that could be what's causing the problem? Yeah that's definitely it, hold on.

Comment: Ok, I added all the css you edited in, and I edited the fancybox CSS code to include the links to the image files. Is there any other reason you could think of that it's not working?

Comment: `<script type="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">` ?? YOu should wrap it in `<script type="text/javascript">` !

Answer (score 1):

```
function openClosePopup (el) {
    window.opener.location.href = el.href;
    window.close();
    return true;
}
```

So your HTML is

```
<a href="#some_url" onclick="return !openClosePopup(this)">Click me</a>
```

For opening a popup you may use the same trick:

```
function openPopup (el) {
    window.open(el.href,'name','height=400,width=200');
    return true;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<a href="#some_url" onclick="return !openPopup(this)">Open windows</a>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this, so the first function is to close the popup and get the url to go to? and what is the first html for?

Comment: If you use this HTML the function will load the URL from the link and close the current window, see `el.href`. If you do not use a link on your page, you may want to modify the function to use the url as parameter.